Delete Group Join service messages in Python-telegram-bot
I have the following code in Python-Telegram-bot library version 13.7, designed to delete service messages in the group:
if (message.new_chat_members or message.left_chat_member or message.new_chat_title or
              message.new_chat_photo or message.delete_chat_photo or message.group_chat_created or
              message.supergroup_chat_created or message.channel_chat_created or message.migrate_to_chat_id or
              message.migrate_from_chat_id or message.pinned_message):

But, what is happening now, is that if a user joins a group through an invitation link (Joined to the group via invite link) or through a confirmation from the group admin (Was accepted into the group), the bot does not recognize this as a service notification of a user joining the group.
What can I do? I tried to do with Message.text so that it recognizes the specific words in messages sent, but because service messages are not regular text messages, it doesn't recognize it despite that.
What can I do?
